# Change the absolute position of a div tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag declared like this:

```
<div id="carRight" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:170px;">
<img src="carRight.png" width="256" height="256" />
</div>
```

After a quick animation, I'd like to move the left position when a button is pressed.  I tried a few variations of this, but it doesn't seem to be correct:

```
document.getElementById('carRight').style.left=600;
document.getElementById('carRight').style.position.left=600;
```

What is the correct statement to use?  Thanks.

Comment: I'll be the pedant to point out that you're probably better off relegating styles to your CSS. Then it's a matter of adding or changing class of that element to effect the change.

Comment: All CSS values must have units like `px`, `pt`, etc...  And, they are string values, not numbers.  So, setting `style.left=600` will do nothing.  It must be `style.left="600px"`.  In addition, if position isn't already set to `absolute` or `relative`, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('carRight').style.left="600px";
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById('carRight').style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:170px;";`

where `100px` is new left position... `position:absolute;` part could be moved to class...

Answer (score 0):

It is not essential to write `element.style.left="600px";`. Just add 
`document.getElementById('carRight').position='relative';`.